# SOAP with WS-Security UsernameToken for Cocoa (Touch)

Tags: cocoa-touch, soap, ws-security

I am looking for a library / code generator that supports the UsernameToken profile of WS-Security for using a SOAP webservice.

I looked at wsdl2objc and WSClient++, but neither of them seem to support it. It would of course be possible to add it to the code, but then I'd have to do it all over again when I generate the code anew after a change to the webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any libraries that really solve the issue, but I found out that it is rather easy to patch the necessary functionality into wsdl2objc, which is open source and works a lot better than WSClient++. I will submit a patch to them as soon as I have cleaned up my patch a little.

This is a strong warning against WSClient++. It's bad code quality and not open source. Do not buy the license. It will cause you only headaches.

Comment: Please change your last line, WSClient++ generates source code, the generated source code and additional library both are in source form, so how can it not be an open source? Secondly, demo version has limitation of not releasing memory, this commercial limitation no way means bad code quality.